# jQuery : ajax not posting to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hello you naughty code animals..

I have tried to get this code to work, and also searching it up. But i find no up-to-date answer i can understand.
So i'll give you the form, then the jQuery.

FORM:

```
<div id="blab_form_overcontent">
    <table border="0" align="center">
        <form id="submit_blab" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="blab_title" id="blab_title" value="" placeholder="title(optional):"/><br/>
        <textarea name="blab_text" id="blab_text" value="" placeholder="text:"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" id="blab_submitb" name="blab_submitb" value="Post"/>
        </form>
        <div class="success" style="display: none;">Blab has been added.</div>
    </table>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("form#submit_blab").submit(function() {
  // I store the values from the form input box, then send via ajax below
  var blab_title   = $('#blab_title').attr('value');
  var blab_text    = $('#blab_text').attr('value');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "classes/profileActions.php",
        data: "blab_title="+ blab_title +"&amp; blab_text="+ blab_text,
        success: function(){
            $('form#submit_blab').hide(function(){$('div.success').fadeIn();});

        }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

NOTE: i know its not my profileActions.php that is the problem because the code over dont get as far as posting anything. It reloads the page only.

Regards,
-Clueless idiot.

Comment: see my updated answer for a few other changes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's refreshing the page because you aren't telling it to NOT refresh the page. :)

```
$('#submit_blab').submit(function(e){
  //start with preventing the default submit action...
  e.preventDefault();

  var blab_t   = $('#blab_title').val();
  var blab_txt    = $('#blab_text').val();

  var json = { blab_title: blab_t, blab_text: blab_txt }      

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "classes/profileActions.php",
    data: json,
    success: function(){
        $('form#submit_blab').hide(function(){$('div.success').fadeIn();});
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: what is the function(e) ? i dont understand the "e" in there sir.

Comment: The (e) is the event object. preventDefault() is an event method to stop whatever the default action was, and to allow you to form your own action.

Comment: `return false` will stop the default behavior.

Comment: yeah i already have return false there, but its not doing the job

Comment: $('#submit_blab').submit(function(e){
  //start with preventing the default submit action...
  e.preventDefault();
});
didnt work, could it be something else in there that is the problem?

Comment: Open up your browser inspector (or firebug or whatever you use). Look for errors being thrown in your console. You may also have some invalid js somewhere that is breaking your whole script. The e. preventDefault WILL work! See my edited post in a minute... I have a feeling you didn't put it all together.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but still refreshing on submit. i have the latest jquery.js. i guess i'll just do a normal html post with refresh.

Comment: Nah, don't give up! You can do it man, it'll feel great when you get it figured out. What does your console say? Do you have any bugs in your script? How about console.log( $('#submit_blab') ) to make sure that the form is being appropriately grabbed by jQuery?

Comment: To be honest, i dont know what console you mean. I rent a host at iPage, linktube dot net is the domain im experiencing on. But still very new to javascript. Its chinese to me.

Comment: ah okay. Okay so if you are using Google Chrome go ahead and right click on the page. In the menu, choose "Inspect Element." Then, click on the icon that says "Console." If you have any bugs in your syntax or script, it'll tell you exactly where to find them.

Comment: cant see any errors in the chrome console Mr Blancarte. I dont mean to sound negative by the way!

Comment: Hmmm... well I'm stumped. If I could see the page you are trying to run, I could tell you how to fix it most likely. No worries you don't sound negative.

Comment: I will update a line of php so you can see and use the form i am implementing on this profile.
Here is the link: linktube . net/profile-15.html  ->Blabs

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the refresh issue mentioned in another answer, your `data` query string is odd. You don't need to encode the `&` and there are extra spaces in there.  Better to use an object literal instead:

```
// Instead of:
data: "blab_title="+ blab_title +"&amp; blab_text="+ blab_text,

// Use an object literal:
data: {
  "blab_title": blab_title, 
  "blab_text": blab_text
},
```

Comment: Yep. He could also serialize the form. Either way is better than what he has going.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use `serialize()` to pass the data in POST

```
 data: $("#submit_blab").serialize(),
```

Also, you might as well change submit to click

```
 $("#blab_submitb").click(function(e)
```